# Why does PTPCamera launch with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu

For some odd reason every time I use Xcode on the latest El Capitan beta, my CPU starts spiking and I start hearing the fans in the computer. I decided to check Activity Monitor and realized `PTPCamera` was the culprit.

Why is it being launched and what is it being used for? Quitting the process doesn't affect Xcode in any way and the CPU usage returns to normal. There are no other devices connected to my computer other than my iPhone.

I'd be very grateful for an answer because this is getting really frustrating. The only helpful link I found online was this [one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3821361?tstart=0).

**Image:**
[image]